# Detecting changes in ListIndex of a ComboBox in VB6

Tags: events, combobox, vb6

I have a `ComboBox` (Style 2 - Dropdown list) in a Form, in VB6.
I want to detect when the `ListIndex` changes.
From my experience and what I found around, I already concluded that the `Click` event should be used (not the `Change` event), but I did not find specific examples.
What I conceived involves using a global variable to store the prior state, and compare against that, but I think this is not the best way to do it.

Is there a better way?

PS: I have added several `Sub`s like

```
Private Sub CBO1_Change()
    Dim CurLI As Integer
    CurLI = CBO1.ListIndex
    MsgBox ("CBO1_Change. ListIndex =" & CurLI)
End Sub
```

one for each of the events `Change`, `DropDown`, `GotFocus`, `KeyDown`, `KeyPress`, `KeyUp`, `LostFocus`, `Scroll`, and check exactly what they do, so as to have a certain comparison with documentation.
None of them seem to allow for getting both values (prior to "entering" the `ComboBox`, and after "exiting").

Comment: VB6 does not have "UserForms" so no telling what's going on here.  Are you using VBA hosted in some application instead?  If so you have an incorrect tag: VBA is NOT VB6.

Comment: @Bob77 - PS: VB6 does not have UserForm s, but it has Form s (perhaps you downvoted because of this), and that is what I am using in VB6. So, VB6 is the correct tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect a change on a click whilst being able to access the two changed values then as you say you will need to track the current selection:

```
Private m_currentIndex As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
    m_currentIndex = -1

    ...
End Sub

Private Sub Combo1_Click()
    If (Combo1.ListIndex <> m_currentIndex) Then
        Debug.Print "change from "; m_currentIndex; " to "; Combo1.ListIndex
        m_currentIndex = Combo1.ListIndex
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just as I thought.